# Shiny Tabs with different groups of selection names

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data set of multiple groups, different subject per group, and I'd like to build a shiny app to show the results of each subject in their respective groups with each group being represented as a tab within a `shiny` app. I feel like I am about 95% there and just can't figure out why the second tab refuses to select data (the first tab works perfectly).

Here is what my data look like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(shiny)

groupID <- rep(1:2, each = 5)
Subject <- LETTERS[1:10]
var1 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 1)
var2 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 2)
var3 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 2.5)
var4 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 3)

df <- data.frame(groupID, Subject, var1, var2, var3, var4)

df_long <- df %>%
  melt(., id = c("groupID", "Subject"))
```

Here is my `shiny` approach thus far:

```
## UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Grp1", fluid = T,
             selectizeInput(
               inputId = "Subject",
               label = "Select Subjects",
               choices = df_long %>% filter(groupID == 1) %>% distinct(., Subject) %>% pull(Subject),
               selected = "A",
               multiple = TRUE
             ),
             mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "grp1_plot"))),

    tabPanel("Grp2", fluid = T,
             selectizeInput(
               inputId = "Subject",
               label = "Select Subjects",
               choices = df_long %>% filter(groupID == 2) %>% distinct(., Subject) %>% pull(Subject),
               selected = "F",
               multiple = TRUE
             ),
             mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "grp2_plot")))
  )
)


## Server
server <- function(input, output){

  # get data
  grp1_dat <- reactive({
    dataset1 <- df_long %>%
      filter(Subject %in% input$Subject,
             groupID == 1)
    dataset1
  })

  grp2_dat <- reactive({
    dataset2 <- df_long %>%
      filter(Subject %in% input$Subject,
             groupID == 2)
    dataset2
  })

  # render the plots
  output$grp1_plot <- renderPlot({

    grp1 <- grp1_dat()

    grp1_plot <- ggplot(grp1, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Subject)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = 1.1) +
      geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1, ymax = 1),
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = Inf,
                fill = "light grey") +
      geom_col(alpha = 0.8, 
               position = position_dodge()) +
      ylim(-4, 4)

    print(grp1_plot)
  })

  output$grp2_plot <- renderPlot({

    grp2 <- grp2_dat()

    grp2_plot <- ggplot(grp2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Subject)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = 1.1) +
      geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1, ymax = 1),
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = Inf,
                fill = "light grey") +
      geom_col(alpha = 0.8, 
               position = position_dodge()) +
      ylim(-4, 4)

    print(grp2_plot)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can see from the screenshots of my app that `shiny` has the two tabs but only tab1 works while tab2 produces an error and I'm not certain how to correct it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't recycle on shiny change inputid to Subject2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(shiny)

groupID <- rep(1:2, each = 5)
Subject <- LETTERS[1:10]
var1 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 1)
var2 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 2)
var3 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 2.5)
var4 <- rnorm(n = length(Subject), mean = 0, sd = 3)

df <- data.frame(groupID, Subject, var1, var2, var3, var4)

df_long <- df %>%
  melt(., id = c("groupID", "Subject"))


## UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Grp1", fluid = T,
             selectizeInput(
               inputId = "Subject",
               label = "Select Subjects",
               choices = df_long %>% filter(groupID == 1) %>% distinct(., Subject) %>% pull(Subject),
               selected = "A",
               multiple = TRUE
             ),
             mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "grp1_plot"))),

    tabPanel("Grp2", fluid = T,
             selectizeInput(
               inputId = "Subject2",
               label = "Select Subjects",
               choices = df_long %>% filter(groupID == 2) %>% distinct(., Subject) %>% pull(Subject),
               selected = "F",
               multiple = TRUE
             ),
             mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "grp2_plot")))
  )
)


## Server
server <- function(input, output){

  # get data
  grp1_dat <- reactive({
    dataset1 <- df_long %>%
      filter(Subject %in% input$Subject,
             groupID == 1)
    dataset1
  })

  grp2_dat <- reactive({
    dataset2 <- df_long %>%
      filter(Subject %in% input$Subject2,
             groupID == 2)
    dataset2
  })

  # render the plots
  output$grp1_plot <- renderPlot({

    grp1 <- grp1_dat()

    grp1_plot <- ggplot(grp1, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Subject)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = 1.1) +
      geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1, ymax = 1),
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = Inf,
                fill = "light grey") +
      geom_col(alpha = 0.8, 
               position = position_dodge()) +
      ylim(-4, 4)

    print(grp1_plot)
  })

  output$grp2_plot <- renderPlot({

    grp2 <- grp2_dat()

    grp2_plot <- ggplot(grp2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Subject)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = 1.1) +
      geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1, ymax = 1),
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = Inf,
                fill = "light grey") +
      geom_col(alpha = 0.8, 
               position = position_dodge()) +
      ylim(-4, 4)

    print(grp2_plot)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. In the `server` I think you have the `grp2`, `Subject2` filter reversed so I was getting an error. I changed to this, `filter(Subject %in% input$Subject2, groupID == 2)`, and it worked. If you can edit your post I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Done sorry I coded it on my head... Please up vote as well